# MySQL SELECT slow even with an index added

Tags: mysql, sql, database

With the following simple query on a 100K row view, it takes 25 seconds to process.

```
SELECT id
FROM View_MyView 
LIMIT 1
```

The view is pretty complex in that it joins 7 (mostly smaller, some much smaller) tables. I'm struggling to reduce the duration of this query and I'm not clear on the implications of the view here. It seems that when a SELECT is done from the main table involved here (also 100K rows), performance is fine (<1 second).

How might i pursue this?

```
mysql> explain select * from view_myview limit 1
+----+------+--------+--------------------------+----------+--------+----------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | table| type   | possible_keys            | key      | keylen | ref      | rows | Extra                           |
+----+------+--------+--------------------------+----------+--------+----------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | tc   | ALL    | PRIMARY                  | NULL     | NULL   | NULL     |   16 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | t1   | ref    | PRIMARY,colr             | colr     | 2      | tc.id    |   28 | Using where                     |
|  1 | ut   | ref    | t_id                     | t_id     | 4      | t1.id    |    1 | Using index                     |
|  1 | g    | ref    | t1_id,t2_id,sp_id,gf_id  | t1_id    | 4      | ut.t_id  |    9 | Using where                     |
|  1 | gf   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY  | 2      | g.gf_id  |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | t2   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,colr             | PRIMARY  | 4      | g.t2_id  |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | s    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY  | 1      | g.sp_id  |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | tc2  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY  | 1      | t2.colr  |    1 |                                 |
```

Comment: Can you show the output of EXPLAIN and the definition of the view?

Comment: Please show original schema that the view was created from.

Comment: [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-algorithms.html), does your view contain any of the listed constructs that prevent mysql from using the `MERGE` algorithm?

Comment: @Shawn, the original schema is quite large.  does the explain indicate anything?

Comment: your view does group by anything?

Comment: The view has an ORDER BY clause but not GROUP BY.

Comment: simplifying the view to remove the ORDER BY does not help performance.

Comment: @glutz could you put the view's code into SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) and post a link here?  Seeing the view's definition will give us a good chance of resolving - if we can also see the underlying table definitions and index definitions so much the better.

Comment: try removing the associated tables one by one to see if you can find what adds the most.

Comment: @JohnLBevan. unfortunately, im not permitted to expose the entire schema here.  does the explain indicate anything suspicious.  is it just a function of the 7 joins in the View?

Comment: @glutz can you anonymise the view's schema and then post (e.g. replace table and column names with more generic ones such as `table1`, `column1`, etc?

Comment: yes, but it'll take a while.  i'll do that (unless there's any worthwhile random speculation i can try more quickly...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View had 7 joins and where clause.  The answer was to sub query the first select based on the where clause. the view hid the complexity from me.